# Error: illegal character: '`'

Tags: android, illegal-characters

when i trying rebuild my project in Android Studio,i got error: illegal character: '`' in

```
public static final int `=0x7f070006;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: please read basics

Comment: looks like you are missing Java basics. do some basics training before you continue

Answer (score 3):

**1** - Give your integer variable a name

and

**2** - Remove that offending character (it's an integer, not a string).

---

By the way, it seems you're trying to edit the R.java file.
You should **never** do that!

Answer (score 0):

what is "`"?

Are you trying to declare a variable name?

A variable name should start with a valid character, lest a unicode one.

try to give a valid name for the variable.

**UPDATE**

If you are refereing this from R.java, then probably you have given this

> `

character in some of the id field. Use Ctrl + Shift + F and paste this character, find where it occurred, remove it for some valid one. Then recompile.

Comment: ... why? it's an integer, not a string.

Comment: @Fantômas in this case, `\`` is a resource id, originating from `XML`... somehow been processed by `AAPT`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I highly doubt that a **`** would ever be part of an **int**.

Comment: @Fantômas so how it got into there ...if not from `android:id="@+id/\`"`? I'd agree as far as, that this should not have been processed, while the result hint for just that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It seems obvious to me that the OP edited the resource file